# Powershell Regex capture group not being inserted in replace

Tags: regex, powershell, capture-group

I have a string

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\"
```

that I am trying to escape the spaces in and turn into

```
"C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0'\Common7\IDE\"
```

my regex code is

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\" -replace '(?<=\\)(?<loc>.*?\s+.*?)(?=\\)', "'${loc}'"
```

but for some reason my outut is

```
"C:\''\''\Common7\IDE\"
```

any insight on why this might be happening?

Comment: change the replacement part to `'$1'`

Comment: changing the code just to -replace '(?<=\\)(?<loc>.*?\s+.*?)(?=\\)', '$1'
puts in the correct replacement, but not the needed ' is there an escape character for this?

Comment: You need to escape the `$` from powershell (so the regex engine sees it). Use `"'`$1'"`. That also works with your original attempt at the named group.

Comment: that works, also just found that -replace '(?<=\\)(?<loc>.*?\s+.*?)(?=\\)', '''${loc}''' also works.

Answer (score 4):

either

```
-replace '(?<=\)(?<loc>.*?\s+.*?)(?=\)', '''${loc}'''
```

or

```
-replace '(?<=\)(?<loc>.*?\s+.*?)(?=\)', "'$loc'"`
```

works

The reason  '''${loc}''' works is because '' is the escape sequence for ' (not \' like the rest of regex). the reason "'$loc'"` works, is because the $ needs to be escaped so that powershell does not parse it before passing it into the regex engine.

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, a few words of explanation would go a long way to making this answer valuable to future readers.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Please post it with the answer so it's clear to future readers.

Comment: I use the back-tick ` to escape the $ when passing it to the regex engine.